# How to store settings in UWP Application?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a UWP project in Visual Studio. I want to keep my settings. Example: Text wrapping is turned on by default. When the user changes this value, my app will keep this value and my app will load in my settings when it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In UWP this is very simple:

It stores the data object at the position given by val.

Functions:

```
public static void SaveSettings(string val, object data)
{
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[val] = data.ToString();
}

public static string GetSettings(string val, string defaultValue = "")
{
    return ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[val] as string ?? defaultValue;
}
```

Usage:

```
//Save data false for the value "TextWrapping":
SaveSettings("TextWrapping", false);

//Retrieve the data from "TextWrapping" and convert it back to bool
bool TextWrapping = bool.Parse(GetSettings("TextWrapping"));

//Usage of the defaultValue:
//When no data has ever been saved to the value "TextWrapping" it is null. So the function returns the provided defaultValue:
bool TextWrapping = bool.Parse(GetSettings("TextWrapping"), "false");
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/settings-learning-track) the official documentation

Comment: Do I need to write the functions you typed in the Settings class?

Comment: I forgot to say that the design pattern of my project is MVVM. Will the code you write be for MVVM?

Comment: You probably can create a Settings class, but that's on your side.

Comment: No, they are not for MVVM. It's only the base of how you can save and restore settings.  Now you can build on it.

Comment: I saw JSON.NET nuget package. Is it possible to keep my settings with Json.NET?

Comment: Yes you can also use json

Comment: How can I store my settings with using Json.NET?

Comment: I guess, that's another question for here

Comment: @MinecraftWolf Settings needs to be saved with key value pairs. You can definitely save JSON strings as value. In FrozenAssassine's example, what you need to do is just replace the false value of `SaveSettings("TextWrapping", false);` into a JSON string that you generated.

Comment: How can I load my settings.

Comment: @MinecraftWolf FrozenAssassine's example contains a `GetSettings` method, you could get the value based on the key and get the corresponding value. If you saved a JSON string, then you will get a JSON string.